# How can I add the index of value of a table to a point on a graph?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, labels

I would like to add to each branch of my polar comb graph the index value as a label.

I give you my code and a screenshot with what I would like to have:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    visualization depends on=x \as \pgfplotspointx,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.style={
        rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
        append after command={
            node [
                anchor=south,
                rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
                shift={(axis direction cs:0,(12.75-\pgfplotspointmeta))}
            ] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointx}^\circ$}
        }
    },
width=4.2\textwidth,
xmin=-1,xmax=45.01, ymin=12, ymax=15,
title=Displacement 12N,
grid=both,
minor x tick num={4}, 
minor y tick num={1},
]
\addplot+[polar comb ,data cs=cart, mark size=1, mark=asterisk] table {
13.8893888888889    0
13.8875152609215    0.256057893044211
13.8818942709919    0.512013162090311
13.8725256030249    0.767763280177719
13.8594087369111    1.02320591422122
13.8425429585071    1.27823902144993
13.8219273735841    1.53276094524909
13.7975609256787    1.78667051020809
13.7694424177793    2.03986711617976
13.7375705377745    2.29225083115874
13.7019438875704    2.54372248278928
13.6625610157771    2.79418374831654
13.6194204538470    3.04353724279891
13.5725207555396    3.29168660540349
13.5218605395737    3.53853658361110
13.4674385353184    3.78399311516262
13.4092536313646    4.02796340758379
};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you are using. It makes it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a node containing the `\coordindex` to `every node near coord/.style`

```
every node near coord/.style={
    rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
    append after command={
    node [
        anchor=south,
        rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
        shift={(axis direction cs:0,(12.75-\pgfplotspointmeta))}
    ] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointx}^\circ$}
    node [ % this is the index node
        anchor=south,
        rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
        text=black,
        shift={(axis direction cs:0,(13.4-\pgfplotspointmeta))}
    ] {\coordindex}
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    visualization depends on=x \as \pgfplotspointx,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.style={
        rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
        append after command={
        node [
            anchor=south,
            rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
            shift={(axis direction cs:0,(12.75-\pgfplotspointmeta))}
        ] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointx}^\circ$}
        node [
            anchor=south,
            rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
            text=black,
            shift={(axis direction cs:0,(13.4-\pgfplotspointmeta))}
        ] {\coordindex}
    }
},
width=4.2\textwidth,
xmin=-1,xmax=45.01, ymin=12, ymax=15,
title=Displacement 12N,
grid=both,
minor x tick num={4}, 
minor y tick num={1},
]
\addplot+[polar comb ,data cs=cart, mark size=1, mark=asterisk] table {
13.8893888888889    0
13.8875152609215    0.256057893044211
13.8818942709919    0.512013162090311
13.8725256030249    0.767763280177719
13.8594087369111    1.02320591422122
13.8425429585071    1.27823902144993
13.8219273735841    1.53276094524909
13.7975609256787    1.78667051020809
13.7694424177793    2.03986711617976
13.7375705377745    2.29225083115874
13.7019438875704    2.54372248278928
13.6625610157771    2.79418374831654
13.6194204538470    3.04353724279891
13.5725207555396    3.29168660540349
13.5218605395737    3.53853658361110
13.4674385353184    3.78399311516262
13.4092536313646    4.02796340758379
};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast answer!!! Just Perfect!